# Bash script : select lines starting with number in specific range

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a file containing lines like:

```
121<some letters> random text ...
1234<some letters> random numbers etc...
```

Each line starts with a number followed by some letters.I'm looking for a way to select only the lines which start with a number in a specific interval, for example : [0-9999] . I'm having difficulty in selecting these lines if the number of digits can vary.

Tried using grep but can't seem to find the correct way to write the regex.

Comment: Did you want to print the line which starts with `0000` ?

Comment: There will be no such lines, only integers in an interval starting from 0 to a few thousand

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk '($1+0)>10 && ($1+0)<50' file
```

would print lines that start with a number from 11 to 49 inclusive.

Comment: I think OP needs `[0-9999]` range

Comment: @anubhava the range can be adjusted :D

Comment: @Alex: Not sure you're getting it. Try running: `awk '($1+0)>=0 && ($1+0)<5000' file`

Comment: @anubhava ... i understand. I meant the range from Ed's example can be adjusted , only needed to know how to write the expression. Thank you for your concern.

Answer (score 1):

Through grep,

```
grep -E '^([1-9][0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]|[0-9])\b' file
```